# Get release version instead of app-debug.apk

Tags: android-studio

Android builds application app-debug.apk as default. Trying to get release version by selecting `release` in `Build Variants`, but getting the same result.

[image]

How to get not debug version?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, close that window.

- On the top menu, click on **Build** > **Generate signed Bundle/APKs**.
- Fill in the dialog boxes that pop up based on your requirements. Soon enough, your release APK would be generated.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!